# Insert date into separate columns

Tags: php, pdo

I have the following code where i enter readings and the current date into a database:

```
$estmt = $this->dbconn->prepare("
    INSERT INTO elec_readings
        (ElecUsage, DateAdded, AccountNumber) 
    VALUES
        (:eUsage, NOW(), :accNum)");
    $estmt->bindparam(":eUsage", $eUsage);
    $estmt->bindparam(":accNum", $_SESSION['user_session']);
    $estmt->execute();  
    return $estmt;
```

Currently it inserts the whole date into one field, I want to change it so that the Day, Month and Year are in their own respective columns/fields, I was just wondering if theres a way to do that instead of using `NOW()`

Comment: You don't want it. Just keep with single field.

Comment: I need it because i want to create a graph based on the month and the reading value

Comment: Graphs has nothing to do with databases. You are supposed to split date in parts at select time.

Comment: But the graph im creating is using the data pulled from the database.

Comment: So ask a database to pull the data in the desired format

Comment: So just pull the month out from the date thats currently in the database?

Comment: Yes, exactly. This is what proper data formats are for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you ask a bank to store your money exclusively in 100 dollar bills, for the reason you prefer these notes?

I doubt so.

Generally you don't care whether there are any physical bills or tot. You just come up to ATM and get some cash, whatever notes you wish.

SAME HERE.

You ask a database to store your date. Whichever format it is using internally - none of your concern. As long as a database understands that this column holds a date value. Thus you are supposed to always use the proper format.

Yet as soon as you need your money back, you come up to the database and get your money in the bills of choice.

```
SELECT MONTH(DateAdded) as `month`, * ...
```

In your case